# Boost::Thread: Removing a thread from a dynamic group?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

Consider this context:

Having a group of threads doing some work (that work is in a infinite loop, embedded project) where the number of threads (and some parameters) depends from a Database result.

What I need is to remove or create threads from that group when there´s a change in the database.

Here is the code:

```cpp
for (result::const_iterator pin = pinesBBB.begin(); pin != pinesBBB.end(); ++pin)
{
    string pinStr = pin["pin"].as<string>();
    boost::thread hiloNuevo(bind(WorkPin, pinStr));
    Worker.add_thread(&hiloNuevo);
}
```

Where `result` is `pqxx::result` from pqxx library.

This piece of code iterates a table from an SQL query result and creates a thread for every record found.

After that, there´s this code that checks the same table every a couple of minutes:

`

```
void ThreadWorker(boost::thread_group *worker, string *pinesLocales)
{
    int threadsVivosInt = worker->size();
    string *pinesDB;
    int contador;
    for (;;)
    {
        contador = 0;
        sleep(60);
        try
        {
            result pinesBBB = TraerPines();
            for (result::const_iterator pin = pinesBBB.begin(); pin != pinesBBB.end(); ++pin)
            {
                pinesDB[contador] = pin["pin"].as<string>();
                contador++;
            }
            thread hiloMuerto
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            sleep(360);
        }
    }
}
```

`

What I want to do is access this thread_group `worker` and remove one of those threads.

I´ve tryed using an Int index like `worker[0]` and with thread´s ID `boost::thread::id`

I can remove a thread using a `native_handle` and then using an plattform specific like `pthread_cancel` but I can´t get the thread from the thread group.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

boost::thread_group::remove_thread() removes the specified thread from a given thread_group.  Once you've done this, you're now responsible for managing the thread.

Comment: Yes, but the only way to find a thread from that group is passing the thread pointer. I can´t find a thread by an index or an ID.

Comment: If this is the case, then you'll need to keep a pointer to each thread in secondary container that is indexed appropriately. Once you have the id/index of the thread you want to remove, look it up in your index and then remove it from the thread_group

Comment: I guess that it´s the only way to go, thank you @Bukes